# Warning: ftp_login(): Not logged in, need secure connection

Tags: php

How to connect sftp using ftp_connect. I know ssh_connect should work for this. But my server is shared hosting there is no option to enable ssh extension.

```
<?php 
    $ftp = ftp_connect('sftp.testsite.com'); 
    echo ftp_login($ftp, 'aaass', 'as333');
?>
```

Your help appreciated to resolve this...

Comment: did you search it on google? ('How to connect sftp using ftp_connect.')

Comment: Tried many ways no luck. So that i'm here some can already worked like this.

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172289/connection-to-secure-ftp-server-from-php

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`ftp_ssl_connect()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-ssl-connect.php) function

Answer (score 1):

ssh2_connect is the best way to connect secure connection. Anyway it will ask the secure connection while your are logging using ftp_connect

```
$port = 5312;
$connection = ssh2_connect('www.yoursecureserver.com', $port);
```

Comment: Quoting the OP, "my server is shared hosting there is no option to enable ssh extension".

Answer (score 0):

Try [phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/sftp/intro.html). eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');
include('Crypt/RSA.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.tld');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
```